# What is different between User Access Token in Profile Page Source and Graph API Explorer?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I go to my Facebook Profile and view Page Source and find "access_token", then I get this access token

```
EAAAAUaZA8jlABAPGC0YNn[some funny charracters]bGxJOgyqAUsZA8N6
```

Then I go to Facebook Graph API Explorer and get User Access Token (I checked all permissions in diablog) and I get another access token

```
EAACEdEose0cBABAiZCsH[some another funny charracters]L4loBTexLEZD
```

What is different between 2 access token ?

Comment: One is one that Facebook uses. One is the one for your app

Comment: Thanks, How to I use Access token to make a Request using PHP SDK Facebeook ? Because I want to use Facebook Access Token instead of Token for App.

Comment: No you don't want to use Facebook Access Token. That will get you banned directly. It is against Facebook Terms of Service and Facebook Platform Policy

Comment: what´s the point anyway? why not just use your own token?

Comment: If I use Facebook Access Token, I can access to group I joined. With Access Token for App, I can't do that.

Comment: If the group is not public, then you only have access if you are an administrator for the group. If you have a legitimate use case, ask an admin to authorize your app and grant it the necessary access. If not, don't try to circumvent the limitations put in place by Facebook.

Comment: So there is no safe way to get data from closed group ? Can I scraping or some another way to do that ?